# Checkout as Guest = "Please make sure your passwords match"

Tags: checkout, password

I found an error in my e-commerce website when I tried to checkout a product as guest.

When I try to continue the process, I get this message:

[image]

I would like to know how I can fix this issue.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Note: I did this but the error still appears  https://www.envisionecommerce.com/please-make-sure-your-passwords-match-magento-1-9-1-0/

Answer (score 1):

First you need to copy Customer.php file from `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model` to  `app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model` path directory and go to line number 843 and find the code.

```
$confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();

In this file you need to replace above code by below code

$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) 
{
  $confirmation = $this->getPasswordConfirmation();

} else {
   $confirmation = $this->getConfirmation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a custom theme or module Checkout OnePage. Compare your theme/module file register.phtml with the default file register.phtml Magento. Keyword - confirmation.

Comment: Probably, there's something wring here, right? http://i.imgur.com/aANRYQ6.png

Answer (score 0):

We tried this and it worked - partly. I do not get the 'please make sure your passwords match' error, but in the 'payment methods' I now get an unknown error (redirects to the shopping cart again). Did you also have this problem? Does someone knows what to do?